PlatformNotSupported when converting WCF client config to C# .NET 6 code
Can anyone share if it is possible for the below configuration to be written in .NET Core? If there are any obvious roadblocks and if there are any workaround.
I have used the code equivalent for the configuration tags I could find with the System.ServiceModel 6.0.0 package. Currently, I'm running into a PlatformNotSupported exception.
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="WifNetTcpServiceBinding">
            <transactionFlow transactionProtocol="WSAtomicTransaction11" />
            <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="SecureConversation" requireDerivedKeys="false">
                <secureConversationBootstrap defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="false" >
                    <issuedTokenParameters >
                        <additionalRequestParameters>
                            <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="">
                                <trust:TokenType xmlns:trust="">http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1</trust:TokenType>
                                <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/SymmetricKey</trust:KeyType>
                            </trust:SecondaryParameters>
                            <apm:RequireUniqueDomainName xmlns:apm="">false</apm:RequireUniqueDomainName>
                            <apm:EpCode xmlns:apm="">APM</apm:EpCode>
                        </additionalRequestParameters>
                        <issuer address="" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecurityTokenServiceBinding">
                            <identity>
                                <certificate encodedValue="AwAAAAEAAAAU" />
                                <dns value="abp-app3.abp.local" />
                                <userPrincipalName value="abp-svc@abp.local" />
                            </identity>
                        </issuer>
                        <issuerMetadata address="https://abp-app3.abp.local:8035/apm/core" />
                    </issuedTokenParameters>
                    <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
                    <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
                </secureConversationBootstrap>
            </security>
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
    <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecurityTokenServiceBinding">
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </ws2007HttpBinding>
</bindings>

Tried trial and error with the methods from ServiceModel nuget package.
The gist of the configuration C# code I have
var issuedTokenParams = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.IssuedSecurityTokenParameters();
var securityBootstrapElement = System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement
               .CreateIssuedTokenOverTransportBindingElement(issuedTokenParams);

var securityBindingElement = System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement.CreateSecureConversationBindingElement(securityBootstrapElement);

// Custom Binding
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
result.Elements.Add(securityBindingElement);
result.Elements.Add(new System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement());
result.Elements.Add(new System.ServiceModel.Channels.SslStreamSecurityBindingElement());

// TCP transport
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpTransportBindingElement tcpTransport = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpTransportBindingElement
            {
                TransferMode = System.ServiceModel.TransferMode.Streamed,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                ConnectionBufferSize = 32768,
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647
            };

result.Elements.Add(tcpTransport);


Well, some people would say you are trying to ride a dead horse ... Are you trying to upgrade something rather legacy to .Net 6 - which soon will be out of support, too?

@Fildor For now, Yes moving from framework app to a .Net app.

And only the client side or wcf service, too? Because if you are going to update client and service, I'd probably consider switching to something like gRPC. Which is considerably more work -- at first, but wcf - tbh I think is taking its last breaths.

@Fildor Appreciate the suggestion but sadly I cannot modify the wcf service. It is not managed by us. I just have control over the WCF client side. I was hoping I could upgrade the client and get the binding to work or at least understand why it is not allowing me to proceed.

If your WCF client is a client referencing a WCF service. All you need to do is create a new project in ASP.NET Core and reference WCF. It automatically generates Reference.cs files.
I think you're referring to WCF services. You should have a problem upgrading your WCF service to ASP.NET Core.
Because ASP.NET Core does not support ServiceModel, many of the features of ServiceModel cannot be implemented on ASP.NET Core. In recent years, CoreWCF has been introduced, which can help you write WCF services on ASP.NET Core. But not all the features have been transferred. I looked at the costumbinding method in Corewcf and some of your config doesn't show up in his method. So I don't think you should just upgrade the code, but look at the source code of Corewcf to try to get closer to your expectations.
Corewcf

I just read the docs and ws2007httpbinding is not supported on ASP.NET Core. So it's hard to do it by modifying the code. Again, it is recommended to change the service to gRPC and ASP.NET Core Web api.
